NameError: name 'LangchainLLM' is not defined
I am following some tutorials online relating to RAG systems. As part of it I am trying to use LangChainLLM from LlamaIndex. I am working on Google Colab. As per the LlamaIndex docs I have imported LangChainLLM as follows:
from llama_index.llms.langchain import LangChainLLM
This does not throw an error when run
However when I try to use LangChainLLM as follows:
langchain_llm = LangchainLLM(llm_chain=llm_chain)
It throws the error NameError: name 'LangchainLLM' is not defined
I have checked the documentation and searched online for a solution but I cant see why this error is arising. I have rerun the notebook but there is no impact.  If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated

you have a typo error LangChainLLM not  LangchainLLM(llm_chain=llm_chain)

You have a typo error LangChainLLM not  LangchainLLM(llm_chain=llm_chain)

Thanks so much, can't believe I missed that, I've been over the code so much!

@user26675397 no worries you welcome :)
